# Grouping transactions under one date rather than repeating them in React web app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently building a component that pulls bank transactions from an API and renders them through a map.

However, it's not very clever. Currently, it looks like this:

[image: An image showing four transactions, three with the same date.]

As you can see, the dates, despite being the same, are grouped separately - which is because of how I've built the map.

However, I want instead to group the transactions that all exist on one date under a single date if that makes sense.. So rather than having three transactions from the 9th Jan, it would instead have one '2021-01-09' title, and the three transactions underneath it, before moving on to the next date and so on..

Here would be an example:

[image: An example from Monzo about how I'd want the transactions to actually look]

As things stand, this is currently my transaction map:

```
const Transaction = (props) => {

  const [transactions, setTransactions] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("/api/getTransactions")
    .then((response) => {
      setTransactions(response.data.transactions)
    })
  }, [])

  return (

            { transactions.map((result, index) => {
              return <div className="individual-transaction-history" key={index}>
                <div className="transaction-history-date-container">
                  <p>{result.date}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="transaction-history-data-container">
                  <p>{result.name}</p>
                  <p>£{result.amount}</p>
                </div>

              </div>
            }) }

  )
}
```

So my question is, what would be the most efficient way for me to re-render my transaction code so it replicates image 2, rather than image 1?

Please let me know if more info is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by grouping by date and having two interations. If I understand correctly, this should be a possible solution to showing unique dates and a list of names with their amount under that date (using lodash).

```
const Transaction = (props) => {

const [transactions, setTransactions] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
  axios.get("/api/getTransactions")
  .then((response) => {
    setTransactions(response.data.transactions)
  })
  .then(() => {
    setTransactions(_.groupBy(transactions, 'date'))
  })
}, [])

return (

{ 
  transactions.map((date, dateIndex) => {
    return <div className="individual-transaction-history" key={dateIndex}>
        <div className="transaction-history-data-container">
          <p>{result.date}</p>
        </div>
      <div className="transaction-history-data-container">
        {
          date.map((result, resultIndex) => {
            return <div className="transaction-history-data-container" key={resultIndex}>
              <p>{result.name}</p>
              <p>£{result.amount}</p>
            </div>
          });
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  });
}
```

Comment: Do I need to install something to access lodash? I've never used it before. It's coming up as 'undefined'.

Comment: you will need to run `npm i lodash --save` where your package.json is located, and then have it imported with `import _ from "lodash";`. [lodash docs](https://lodash.com/)